# GPS table of 600000 users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, gps, query-performance

I'm using `mysql`. my programming language is `php`.

I have 600.000 users that I get `lat` and `lon` of these users by cell-phone's gps every 10 seconds once.

some of my queries on this table:

- the nearest of users with a specific `lan` and `lon`.
- to get last `lan` and `lon` of each user every minute.

some of my queries 7-14 seconds take time like:

```
SELECT m1.*
            FROM gps m1 LEFT JOIN gps m2
             ON (m1.driver_id = m2.driver_id AND m1.id < m2.id)
            WHERE m2.id IS NULL
```

I think this table is too big.

<strike>Is it good idea to use thiry-party like `Cloud Bigtable` just for this table?
Is there any solution?</strike>  *Let's first discuss MySQL fixes.*

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `gps` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `trucks_drivers_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `y` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `speed` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;
```

I don't set any `indexs` to this table.

Comment: Please read this, especially the part on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Please [edit] your question to give more details about your table, query, and indexes. Yes, it's big table. Too big?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: Indexes please! Queries you want to optimize, please!

Comment: As you wrote it, preparing the update data and updating that many records every 10 sec would be much bigger performance issue than just querying that table. So you should consider that too. Now your question is too broad.

Comment: For performance issues you should add explain plan too.

Comment: I find it very unlikely every single user needs to update every 10s. I would strongly suggest you look at ways to reduce the rate of updates. At a minimum, users that aren't moving don't need to be sending an update. Such users could, perhaps, send a single update every several/many minutes, or hours. There are, of course, many other possible optimizations (e.g. the phone/system can keep track of velocity and only report if the current position doesn't match (within margin of error) with the predicted position based on the velocity determined from the last two reports, etc.).

Comment: There are many things wrong with the implementation using MySQL.  Let's fix them before asking about alternative technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the `id` of the latest reading for each driver like this.

```
           SELECT MAX(id) id
             FROM gps
            GROUP BY driver_id
```

An index on `(driver_id, id)` will help that query.  Then this query finds the latest position of each driver.

```
       SELECT a.lat, a.lon, a.driver_id
         FROM gps a
         JOIN (
                  SELECT MAX(id) id
                    FROM gps
                   GROUP BY driver_id
              ) b ON a.id = b.id
```

**Pro tip:** Avoid `SELECT *` on performance critical queries, especially from large tables. Instead give the names of columns you need.

**Pro tip:** Shorter columns are faster, especially in large tables. Fixed length columns are faster, especially in large tables. Don't use `varchar(100)` to store lat/lon values. If those values come from GPS use `FLOAT`. If they come from surveying or photogrammetry use `DOUBLE`.  Or consider using the [MySQL Spatial Data Extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html).

Comment: In your tip you suggest to use fixed length. If you have like this case varchar(100) is there a way to check if the max of char is used ? @o-jones So basically is there a way to find the best fixed length if you do not now how many will be used.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(col)) FROM tbl` will show you the longest value in `col`. `SELECT COUNT(*), LENGTH(col) FROM tbl GROUP BY LENGTH(col) ORDER BY 2 DESC` will show you the distribution of lengths. If the column actually contains numeric values, the number of characters in those values doesn't matter, though. You need to put them in numeric columns,  Generally speaking you shouldn't used a fixed character width for data that actualy contain a varying number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM gps m1 LEFT JOIN
     gps m2
     ON m1.driver_id = m2.driver_id AND m1.id < m2.id
WHERE m2.id IS NULL;
```

You want an index on `gsp(driver_id, id)`.  You may already have this index.

According to your question, you would be returning 600,000 rows.  Much of the time may be spent returning the rows, rather than generating the result set.

If you want to handle GIS data, then consider using a [GIS extension](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html).  Switching to a NO-SQL solution could solve some performance problems, but it might introduce others.  You shouldn't switch until you have carefully evaluated the full range of operations that your system needs.

Comment: will there an extreme performance win by changing from innodb to myisam for select queries ? where you need 600k records

Comment: Don't use MyISAM.  Use InnoDB with `PRIMARY KEY(driver_id, id)` to get a performance boost from the "clustering" of the PK.